# Maximizing function on L^p ball

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $u$ be a strictly concave function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  How can one (constructively) find the maximum of
$$
\operatorname{sup}_{f\in B}\int_{x \in X} u(f(x)) dx
,
$$
where $B$ is the unit ball in $L^p(\mu)$ without the ($\mu$-a.e.) constant functions, equipped with the weak-topology.

It does not seem to be obvious, even the simplification I made to $u(x)=log(x^2)$ gives me grief.

Comment: Where did the strictly concave function $F$ show up?

Comment: In a game theory book I'm reading on the mini-max theorem

Comment: I mean, you wrote there is a function $F$ which does not really show up in your question.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out F is u